# Extract surface from matlab .fig

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, surface

I have a matlab .fig file which contains some points and a surface fitted to them. I want to extract the surface from the figure, and I would like to have both the vertices and the faces. Could you please provide me some hints on how to achieve this?

My figure can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By376R0mxORYU3JsRWw1WjllWHc/view?usp=sharing and I would like to extract the surface without the blue points.

EDIT: it is not a duplicate, see my comment below as to why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I extract data from a .fig file in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976505/how-can-i-extract-data-from-a-fig-file-in-matlab)

Comment: @excaza it is not a duplicate, because what I didn't know was how to separate the surface from the points, which was not even implied in that question.

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate, [Yair's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976505/how-can-i-extract-data-from-a-fig-file-in-matlab/4417672#4417672) is the same as what you accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data used to plot either the surface and the dots are stored in the figure.

Therefore you can:

- open the figure
- get the data from the figure
- get the children of the figure, in thsi case the axes
- extract form the axes, the X, y, and z data of the surface

The axes actually contains two set of data:

- the data of the dots stored in the z(1) `XData`, `YData`, `ZData`
- the data of the surface stored in the z(2) `XData`, `YData`, `ZData`

This is the code (with "dot notation"):

```
% Open the figure
open('cubicinterp.fig')
% Get the data from the figure
x=gcf
% Get the children of the figure (in this case the axes)
y=x.Children
% Get the data used to plot on the axes
z=y.Children

figure
XX=z(2).XData;
YY=z(2).YData;
ZZ=z(2).ZData;
CCDD=z(2).CData;
surf(XX,YY,ZZ,CCDD)
return
```

This is the code without the "dot notation" (before R2014b)

```
% Open the figure
open('cubicinterp.fig')
% Get the data from the figure
x=gcf
% Get the children of the figure (in this case the axes)
y_1=get(gcf,'children');
% Get the data used to plot on the axes
z_1=get(y_1,'children');

figure
XX=get(z_1(2),'xdata');
YY=get(z_1(2),'ydata');
ZZ=get(z_1(2),'zdata');
CCDD=get(z_1(2),'Cdata');
surf(XX,YY,ZZ,CCDD)
```

This is the extracted surface:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Qapla'

Comment: you saved my day. Thank you very much for your answer :).

Comment: You're welcome. Happy I've been of use to you. In case it is needed, I've added the code working for MatLab versions older than R2014b (not using the "dot notation".

Comment: My MatLab version is R2015b, so I got it done. Thank you once again for everything :)