# Hi, i have a 3d figure in matlab but i dont have the data , can i get 2d data image from it?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a 3 dimensional figure  but I do not have the data , can i get 2 dimensional data image from it? 
I have tried slice function but i need the original data.

Comment: You can try using [the solution I've proposed in this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37331362/4806927)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a 3 dimensional figure saved in *.fig, right?
you can copy the object by using, copyobj, i.e. new_handle = copyobj(h,p) to new one or copy allchild, child_handles = allchild(handle_list)
you can get 2D data from new_handle.XDATA and new_handle.YDATA