# Animate the deformation of a 2d grid in MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, nodes, mesh

I have created a mesh using C++, consisting of nodes which are connected by springs with corresponding stiffnesses, in the horizontal and vertical directions.

I have displaced the nodes at the top of the mesh and solved the resultant system of equations to find the new nodal positions. The coordinates of the nodes in the unstrained mesh and also the strained mesh have been exported into MATLAB.

The following shows the unstrained points plotted by '*' and the strained points plotted by 'o'. What I want is to show the springs (i.e horizontal and vertical lines connecting the nodes to their neighbours), and also animate the change from the unstrained configuration into the strained configuration.

Has anyone got any ideas of how I would go about this? Any suggestions at all would be good at this stage. I hope I have explained the problem well enough.

[image: unstrained = blue '*', strained = red 'o']Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

So far I have this

```
% Number of nodes in each direction
nx = 3;
ny = 4;

figure;

% Unstrained mesh
subplot(1,2,1)

plot(x0,y0,'ro'), xlim([-1,3]), ylim([-1, 6])

% Draw the horizontal springs
for i = 1 : 12
    if mod(i,nx) == 1 || mod(i,nx) == 2
        line([x0(i),x0(i+1)], [y0(i), y0(i+1)])
    end
end
% Draw the vertical springs
for i = 1 : nx*ny - nx
    line([x0(i),x0(i+nx)], [y0(i), y0(i+nx)], 'Color', 'Black')

end

% Strained mesh
subplot(1,2,2)

plot(x1,y1,'ro'), xlim([-1,3]), ylim([-1, 6])

% Draw the horizontal springs
for i = 1 : nx*ny
    if mod(i,nx) == 1 || mod(i,nx) == 2
        line([x1(i),x1(i+1)], [y1(i), y1(i+1)])
    end
end
% Draw the vertical springs
for i=1:nx*ny
    line([x1(i),x1(i+nx)], [y1(i), y1(i+nx)], 'Color', 'Black')

end
```

[image]
And I wish to make an animation showing the subplot on the left deform into the subplot on the right. The points (node positions) are stored in the x0, y0, and x1, y1 vectors for the unstrained and strained mesh respectively.

Hope this helps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688688/how-to-do-an-animated-plot-in-matlab ? Just replace the plot by whatever you want

Comment: Can you attach an example of what you want? It's unclear to me what the points stand for, and what are springs, but I may help if I understand what you try to do. Also, post a [mcve] of what you got so far.

Comment: @EBH I have edited my post, I hope this helps.

Comment: So you need literally what I linked there then?

Comment: @AnderBiguri No, not at all. What you linked shows how to draw a point. I want to move something that is already drawn.

Comment: What I linked shows how to animate something. If getting the information of your plot is what worries you, read about `get` in the mathworks page and see some examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976505/how-can-i-extract-data-from-a-fig-file-in-matlab. However in the links I shown it shows how to clear the image and replot the poitns creating an animation